# No value is coming in my partial view throught knockout js

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

```
var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';
var viewmodel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.VoucherDetails = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON(baseUri, this.VoucherDetails);
    alert(self.VoucherDetails);
};


<table>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: VoucherDetails'>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text : $data.empcode">
                <span data-bind=" text : $data.empcode"></span> test
            </td>
            <td data-bind=" text : empcode">
                <span data-bind=" text : empcode"></span>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my partial view and there is no value coming in empcode or `$data.empcode`, I am new to `knockoutjs`. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incomplete:

- $.getJson never sets the value of VoucherDetails (no callback is passed).
- You never call ko.applyBindings

It should be:

```
var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';
var viewmodel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.VoucherDetails = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON(baseUri, function(data){
        //create your VoucherDetails here based on the data (push each item to VoucherDetails using $.each
   });  
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: it is working my above code. Actually i was not calling the function anywhere, i just used called it in document.ready(function() and it started working. Thanks for the help though